# What is the most economical way to implement your own window border and title bar?

Tags: wpf, customization

I am pretty new to WPF and am sitting here with my book trying to figure out the best approach to this application.

The title bar is not part of the client area so I am making my own title bar.

Which way would it be easiest to make this into some sort of resource to apply to all new windows I create?

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="WindowTheme">
        <Setter Property="Window.WindowStyle" Value="None"/>

    </Style>
    <!--Would I create a user control here for the title bar/border and title bar buttons? Or would it be a style?-->
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: It would be awesome if the resource could already contain all the event handling code for maximizing, minimizing, closing, re-sizing, and dragging as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, there are two ways to use styles: *Named* styles and *typed* styles. A named style has an `x:Key="..."` attribute. A typed style doesn't have a name, but a `TargetType="..."` attribute (Rem: Named styles can and very often do have a TargetType as well, so *named* styles and *unnamed* styles would be more precise). Typed styles automatically get applied to all controls in the scope, which are of type `TargetType` (not a derived type).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
</Style>
```

To create your own window, you can set it's template property to a UserControl in the style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The professional way to implement the control template is to implement it 'from scratch', this means not using a UserControl which derives from `Window`. To do this, you define the visual tree of the Window, and use the WPF feature *TemplateParts* to define what part of your control template is responsible for what functionality of the window.

Here is a tutorial which describes pretty exactly what you want to do:

[CodeProject tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140267/Create-Custom-Windows-in-WPF-with-Ease)